# Solving a differential equation numerically

Tags: integration

How do you solve the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx+e} $$ where **a, b, c,** **d** and **e** are arbitrary constants? Can anyone suggest any techniques such as numerical integration to do this?

Comment: You should really show us what you have tried, what techniques you have learned to solve the problem etc. so that we can help. The ODE is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Example), and after separation the degree of the denominator is smaller than the degree of the numerator meaning that you can probably apply [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Illustration).

Comment: This is a separable ODE, and hence reduces to the integration of a linear/quadratic. Do you know how to integrate that?

Comment: I think the integral could be something like this $\displaystyle \int\frac{\frac{dx(t)}{dt} dx(t)+e}{c+ax(t)^2+bx(t)}dt=\int 1 dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dx+e}{ax^2+bx+c}=\frac 1a \frac{dx+e}{(x-r)(x-s)}$$ where $(r,s)$ are the roots of the quadratic.

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{dt}{dx} =\frac 1{a(r-s)}\Bigg[\frac{d r+e}{x-r}-\frac{d s+e}{x-s} \Bigg]$$ which does not look to be too difficult.

So, you easily obtain $t(x)$; just inverse it to  get $x(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a separable equation and analytical integration is possible:

$$\int\frac{dx+e}{ax^2+bx+c}dx=t.$$

For integration, decompose $dx+e$ as $p(2ax+b)$, giving $p\log|ax^2+bx+c|$, and a constant remainder. The antiderivative of the inverse of a quadratic trinomial is either an $\arctan$ or $\text{artanh}$ depending on the sign of the discriminant.

Unfortunately, the solution is in implicit form $f(x)=t$.

Answer (score 1):

After some algebra,
you can put the right side
into the form

$px+q+\dfrac{r}{dx+e}
$
where
$p, q,$
and
$r$
depend on
$a, b, c, d,$
and $e$.

After this,
you should be able
to solve the equation.

Comment: This is of little use, you need to integrate the inverse fraction.